# dataframe duplicate column values ​in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have the following dataframe

| column1 | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| None | value 1 |
| None | value 1 |
| None | value 1 |
| None | value 1 |
| value2 | None |

Both columns have the same name.
I want to make these two columns into one column and fill them with values. like this

| column1 |
| --- |
| value1 |
| value1 |
| value1 |
| value1 |
| value2 |

What should I do?

Note that only one of the duplicate columns has a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `None` string values by `NaN` float values, then `stack` which will convert the data to a single column dropping na values as `dropna=True` by default for stack, then finally `unstack`:

```py
df.replace('None', float('nan')).stack().unstack()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   column1
0  value 1
1  value 1
2  value 1
3  value 1
4   value2
```